# Error in SSIS package XML Source : The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, runtime-error

I have got message in my SSIS package.

> SSIS package "C:\Google Диск\UpWork\USPTO\SSIS Project for
>   USPTO\USPTOLoaad\pkgLoad1XMLFile.dtsx" starting. Error: 0xC004801F at
>   Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: The component metadata for "XML
>   Source, clsid {8DC69D45-2AD5-40C6-AAEC-25722F92D6FC}" could not be
>   upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade
>   method failed. Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task 1,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning. Error: 0xC0048021 at
>   Data Flow Task 1, XML Source [2]: The component is missing, not
>   registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The
>   contact information for this component is "Extracts data from an XML
>   file. For example, extract catalog data from an XML file that
>   represents catalogs and catalog items. Before using, specify the
>   schema and generate an output for each XML element.;Microsoft
>   Corporation;Microsoft SQL Server; Microsoft Corporation; All Rights
>   Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;2". Error: 0xC0047017
>   at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: XML Source failed validation and
>   returned error code 0xC0048021. Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task 1,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation. Error:
>   0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task
>   validation.

Environment SQL SERVER 2016 with SP1 in Oracle VM virtual Box, on Windows Server 2012 R2 Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated) Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586 SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.61704.140 SQL Server Integration Services Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version
14.0.500.272

I've tried swith Run64bit runtime in false, didn't help.
I've reinstall DataTools, didn't help.
I've download and install MSXML,didn't help.

XML file for test only, with 1 node. Only one XML Source in Data Flow Task

Answer (score 1):

Problem are solved by uninstall last Data tools version, and install preversion. It was required recreate new SSIS projects, so there isn't converter from hi version to lower.
Stay question - how to install XML source components without downgrade DataTools version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I changed the Taget Server Version for my ssis project to SQL Server 2016 Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution for the XML Source Component (and maybe other components):

If one develops on a recent Version of Visual Studio (in my case 2017) one has to define a target version of the mssql instance to deploy the package to:

[image: Project Properties]

To deploy the package to an older version of MSSQL (in my case 2012) you have to change this target version accordingly. In this moment the visual studio changes all the references to packges, objects and versions ond you get this problem with "unchangeable" XML Source Components, unrunnable packages an all this fuckery.

I think this is because the version number of the component was not properly changed in development for newer versions of mssql - this is an assumption.

Good thing - this took me some time to figure out - you change the target server version back and everything works again. So your development process would look as folows:

1. Develop Project / run debug [TargetServerVersion 2017]
2. Deploy project to mssql (2012) [TargetServerVersion 2012]
3. Develop Project further [TargetServerVersion 2017]

It looks like this "conversion" is done properly and can be done indefinitely. This is an assumption.